# How to use a short key to type a block of text in VIM?

Tags: vim

I want to use a set of short keys, each of which expands to a block of text after I type it.

For example, suppose two short keys are ":greeting", ":lalist", then

- typing "greeting+TAB" (or ":greeting") should expand to

  ```
  Hi, dear user: We are very glad that you have submitted your paper to XXX. 
  XXX is a world renowned conference in the field of YYY. This year, we have 
  about BLABLA.
  ```
- typing "lalist+TAB" (or ":lalist") should expand to

  ```
  \begine{list}
    \item
  \end{list}
  ```

While "snipMate" is well able to expand some keywords, e.g. for c program, it can not expand customized keywords like the above "greeting".

How can I do this?

---

Thanks! I was not aware about the custom expansion feature of snipMate and vim abbreviation.  Problem solved.

Comment: SnipMate _can_ expand customized keywords, you just need to define the blocks yourself in .vim/snippets. But it can also be done with `:abbreviate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for *abbreviations*. See the extensive vim help under `:help abbr`. In short, place this in your `.vimrc`:

```
iabbr :greeting Hi, dear user: We are very glad that you have submitted your paper to XXX.<CR>XXX is a world renowned conference in the field of YYY. This year, we have<CR>about BLABLA.
```

which in this case provides an abbreviation in *insert* mode.